# PHP query fails when adding include

Tags: php, mysql, include

So I'm pretty confused by this.

I have a header that logins to my mysql server for me, so I have the same mysql initialization information all contained in 1 file so if updates need to be made it can be done to all files easily.

I also have another header that uses the mysql initialization header to check the query string appended to the URL. It looks for username and password information and verifies it is in the database, if it is not in the database the server sends a different page saying they lack valid login credentials and serves up another page.

header.php

```
<?php
$host = "host";
$dbUsername = "user";
$dbPass= "pass";
$db = "user";

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$conn = new mysqli($host,$dbUsername,$dbPass,$db);

if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection to server failed!: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if(empty($_POST) == false)
{
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
}
else if(empty($_GET) == false)
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
}

?>

<!-- Put this inside php tags in a form so posts get sent with the proper username and data
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='username' value='" . $username . "'/>";
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='password' value='" . $password . "'/>";
-->
```

invalidlogin.php

```
<?php
if(empty($conn) == true)
{
    include("includes/header.php");
}
?>
<?php
$validlogin = false;

 if(empty($username) == false && empty($password) == false)
 {
     if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username=? AND password=?"))){
         echo "Username check prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
     }

     if(!($stmt->bind_param("ss",$username,$password))){
         echo "Username check bind param failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
     }

     if(!$stmt->execute()){
         echo "Username check execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
     }

     if(!$stmt->bind_result($id))
     {
         echo "Username bind result failed: " . $conn->connect_errno . " " . $conn->connect_error;
     }

     $stmt->fetch();

     if(empty($id) == false)
         $validlogin = true;
 }

if($validlogin == false)
{
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database Restaraunts</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <a href="index.php">
                <h3>Restaraunt Database Project</h3>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="login_container">
            <a href="index.php"><h3>Invalid Login Credential. Return to main page and login.</h3></a>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    exit(0);
}
?>
```

Both of these files will be included in 90% of my other pages. Both these pages work together. However, when I include both in a 3rd file they both continue to function but the sql connection from the header.php no longer works in the 3rd file they are both included in. Error at first query encountered in the 3rd file.

> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /nfs/stak/students/l/lewisch/public_html/select.php on line 38
>
> Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in
>   /nfs/stak/students/l/lewisch/public_html/select.php on line 38 Tag
>   prepare failed:   Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on
>   a non-object in /nfs/stak/students/l/lewisch/public_html/select.php on
>   line 41

The thing is when I do a dump I don't see $conn going out of scope, but that is the behaviour i'm seeing. I'm really new to PHP so I may be misunderstanding something. Note the query's used with my connection perform correctly simply if I remove the 'invalidlogin.php' include.

select.php

```
<?php
include("includes/header.php");
include("includes/invalidlogin.php");    
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Database Restaraunts</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <?php
                echo "<a href='" . "select.php?username=" . $username . "&password=" . $password . "'>\n";
            ?>
                <h3>Restaraunt Database Project</h3>
            </a>
            <div>
               <?php
                    echo "<a href='" . "user.php?username=" . $username . "&password=" . $password . "'>\n";
                    echo "user account: " . $username;
               ?>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="login_container">
            <form class="login">
                <h3>Restaraunt Information</h3>
                <div class="subform">
                    <label class="form_label">Tags</label><br/>
                    <select name="tags" multiple>
                        <?php
                        //Line 38
                        if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, description FROM tag"))){
                            echo "Tag prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }
                        //Line 41
                        if(!$stmt->execute()){
                            echo "Tag check execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }

                        if(!$stmt->bind_result($tid,$description))
                        {
                            echo "Tag bind result failed: " . $conn->connect_errno . " " . $conn->connect_error;
                        }

                        while($stmt->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<option value='" . $tid . "'>" . $description . "</option><br/>\n";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select><br/>

                    <label>Name</label><br />
                    <input name="name" type="text" />
                </div>
                <div class="subform">
                    <label class="form_label">State</label><br />
                    <select name="state">
                    <option value=""></option>
                        <br />
                        <?php
                        if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT state FROM location"))){
                            echo "Username check prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }

                        if(!$stmt->execute()){
                            echo "Username check execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }

                        if(!$stmt->bind_result($state))
                        {
                            echo "Username bind result failed: " . $conn->connect_errno . " " . $conn->connect_error;
                        }

                        while($stmt->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<option value='" . $state  . "'>" . $state . "</option><br/>\n";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select><br />
                    <label class="form_label">City</label><br/>
                    <select name="city">
                      <option value=""></option>
                        <?php
                       if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM location"))){
                            echo "Username check prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }

                        if(!$stmt->execute()){
                            echo "Username check execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }

                        if(!$stmt->bind_result($city))
                        {
                            echo "Username bind result failed: " . $conn->connect_errno . " " . $conn->connect_error;
                        }

                        while($stmt->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<option value='" . $city  . "'>" . $city . "</option><br/>\n";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select><br />
                    <label class="form_label">Zipcode</label><br />
                    <select name="zip">
                       <option value=""></option>
                        <?php
                        if(!($stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT zip FROM location WHERE zip is NOT NULL"))){
                            echo "Username check prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }

                        if(!$stmt->execute()){
                            echo "Username check execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
                        }

                        if(!$stmt->bind_result($zip))
                        {
                            echo "Username bind result failed: " . $conn->connect_errno . " " . $conn->connect_error;
                        }

                        while($stmt->fetch())
                        {
                            echo "<option value='" . $zip  . "'>" . $zip . "</option><br/>\n";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <?php
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='username' value='" . $username . "'/>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' name='password' value='" . $password . "'/>";
                ?>

                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Search" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

<?php
unset($_POST);
?>
```

I think I need something like header guards but I'm not exactly sure how to go about that. I'm trying to check if the $conn variable exists and if it does don't reinitialize the server info, but that isn't working.

This is a class project so I'm sure this isn't the most secure way of doing this. It is just a proof of concept. It is a database class so I'm only being graded on the queries, the rest of the site just has to function and it was my choice to do a basic user login system attached to some other stuff. Not asking questions about information related to what I am being tested on, just why does my sql connection stop working with this additional header and how can I fix it?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Would you mind clearly pointing out line 41 and 38?

Comment: ^ as mentioned this is just for a test project that doesn't need to be secure. I know this isn't the correct methods to secure it, but that is not a concern with this project given it is a class project that simply is to demonstrate basic sql queries in a application.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: Line 41 And 38 our now commented. As mentioned line 41 and 38 function correctly without the invalidlogin.php include.

Given the limited time i have to work on this project and having literally 4 others and job interviews going on I definitely want to learn correctly, but given that is not in the scope of the project I need to budget my time and make sure I get a good grade. After that I can manage extraneous things that will not effect my grade. It is not an excuse. I know this is not how to do it in industry.

Comment: I would change include to require_once, so the file will only be required once. Include will include the file in the position, so the variable scope can be limited